# What are direct and indirect subclasses?

Tags: java

I was looking at Android development documentation, and I saw [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer.html):

```
public abstract class Buffer
extends Object

Known Direct Subclasses:
ByteBuffer, CharBuffer, DoubleBuffer, FloatBuffer, IntBuffer, LongBuffer, ShortBuffer

Known Indirect Subclasses:
MappedByteBuffer
```

`Buffer` is a abstract class that cannot be instantiated. 
It inherits (extends) `Object`.

But I am confused about the direct and indirect subclasses.
My best guess would be: *Direct* extend directly from the superclass.
*Indirect* extends from a superclass that directly extends the class in question.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: You are correct. With _indirect_, the superclass doesn't have to be a direct subtype of the class in question, it can be any number of levels below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct. A *known* direct relationship implies that the class is the immediate ancestor. A *known* in-direct relationship implies that the class is known to be a sub-class, but it may in fact be many levels below the parent.

Answer (score 9):

**Given** `class A`:

```
class B extends A // B is direct subclass of A
class C extends B // C is indirect subclass of A
class D extends C // D is indirect subclass of A
```

you get the point.

**Another way to look at it** is using this inheritance chain graph (A is the superclass, the rest inherits):

```
A->B->C->D
```

B is a direct subclass of A, the rest are indirect subclass of A.